# Stuck on Splash Screen when trying to fetch API in expo production build

Tags: react-native, axios, expo, fetch-api, eas

I encountered a problem when I was trying to fetch data from an API in my preview build in EAS/Expo build. The annoying part is that when I use an emulator (Android Studio), I was able to fetch data like normal and nothing happens, but the problem only occurs in Production Build/Preview Build. I have searched everywhere for the solution but there just isn't enough community surrounding Expo and React Native for me to find anything. Please if anyone has encountered this problem and have solved it, please answer below. Let me know if you need any code snippet or package.json, etc.

At first I tried to use Axios and it worked on Emulator, but on production build, when I click on Log in to send the request to the API for authentication, the app just suddenly switched to the SplashScreen and get stuck there. Then I thought the problem was Axios, so I switch back to built-in FetchAPI, which also does not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.